# `tput setaf` inconsistency + fail (Ventura, Sonoma)

Tags: terminal, iterm, command-line

I'm attempting to customise my bash prompt, so that I get this:

[image]

i.e. user-text is in bold, but stdout is not.

It was working, but after upgrading my mac it's glitching.

Machine A: MacBook Pro 2017 running Ventura.
Machine B: MacBook Pro M2 running Sonoma (Pre-Release).

My bash PS1 prompt (define in ~/.bash_profile) is defined thus:

```bash
function rgb {
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#8-bit
    let "sum = 16 + 36*$1 + 6*$2 + $3"
    # echo "\[\e[${sum}m\]"
    tput setaf ${sum}
}

  BOLD=$(tput bold)
   DIM=$(tput dim)
 RESET=$(tput sgr0)

BRIGHT=$(rgb 5 5 5)
  BLUE=$(rgb 1 1 5)
YELLOW=$(rgb 4 4 1)

PS1="\n"
PS1+=" \[${DIM}\]"
PS1+="\u"
PS1+="${BRIGHT}@"
PS1+="\[${BRIGHT}\]"
PS1+="\h "
PS1+="\[${BLUE}\]"
PS1+="\w "
PS1+="\n"
PS1+="\[${BRIGHT}\]"
PS1+="> "
PS1+="\[${BOLD}\]"
```

Machine A it works:

[image: A works]

Machine B, not quite:

[image: B fails]

And I can't figure out why.

On a given machine there's consistency between Terminal.app, iTerm2 and VSCode Integrated Terminal.

So I went back to basics, and discovered that on both machines, this works correctly:

```bash
> echo -e "\033[32mThis should be green\033[0m"
```

... while this fails (comes out in white):

```bash
> tput setaf 2; echo "This should be green"
```

[image: B-not-green]

I'm surprised to observe this behaviour on machine A, after so many years without noticing any trouble.

So, I'm facing two puzzles:

- why is my prompt failing on machine B
- why is that `tput` failing on both machines?

Should I just be avoiding tput here? I'm guessing I only did it because it looks cleaner than escape sequences.

Comment: What is `$TERM` set to on both machines?  `tput` will interrogate `terminfo` according to the setting of `$TERM` to get the codes it needs to send, while sending escape codes ignores `terminfo` and just hopes it works.  On the failing machine, try `tput setaf 2 | od -h -t c`, and see what `tput` is actually sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to build upwards from scratch.

I won't try to explain this code; GP4 will do a better job!

There was a `${DIM}` that was somehow getting RESET on the old system but not the new system. I don't get it.

All I can say is: now it works!

```bash
function rgb {
    let "sum = 16 + 36*$1 + 6*$2 + $3"
    echo -n "\[\e[38;5;${sum}m\]"
}

BOLD=$(tput bold)
DIM=$(tput dim)
RESET_RAW='\e[0m'
RESET='\[\e[0m\]'

BRIGHT=$(rgb 4 4 4)
BLUE=$(rgb 1 1 5)
YELLOW=$(rgb 4 4 1)

git_branch() {
  git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null
}

PS1="\n"
PS1+="$(rgb 2 2 2)\u"
PS1+="$(rgb 1 1 1)@"
PS1+="$(rgb 2 3 2)\h "            # `sudo scutil --set HostName foo` to set hostname (\h)`
PS1+="${BLUE}\w "
PS1+="${YELLOW}\$(git_branch)"
PS1+="\n"
PS1+="$(rgb 3 3 3)> "
PS1+="${BRIGHT}${BOLD}"

PS2="${BOLD}> ${RESET}"

trap 'echo -ne "${RESET_RAW}" > $(tty)' DEBUG
```

Comment: You should accept the answer to indicate that the problem has been solved.